# Could Acts 12:22 be translated "of God" instead of "of a god"?

Tags: greek, acts, grammar

Acts 12:22 is usually translated something like

> "And they began to shout, “This is the voice of a god, not a man!”"

Can the word translated 'of a god' (Θεοῦ, theou) instead be translated as 'of God', simply in terms of grammar?

Comment: Yes it could; but since the polytheistic Roman populace did not really believe in one supreme God, such a translation is a stretch.

Comment: @Dottard Thanks for this - got it. So the 'they' here refers to pagans.

Comment: The "They" is almost certainly pagans because Jews were unlikely to attend such a gathering.  However, i am sure that one or two Jews were there but the extent to which they participated in such a clamor is unknown but (hopefully) unlikely.

Comment: I think would be incorrect to translate 'of God', because we are take note of the inner structure of the sentence. The two terms translated 'god' and 'man' are both to the genitive case. The unique semantical difference between them is the implied (i.e. not expressed by words) affirmative particle related to the first term ('god'), and the explicit negative particle related to the second term ('man'). (continue)

Comment: The logical structure of the last part of the sentence can be termed A = B; A ≠ C, where 'A' is 'Herod's voice'; 'B' = 'god'; 'C' = 'man'. No translator never ventured (as I know) - correctly - to translate the last part of the verse "...not of (the) Man!", since the verse will become unintelligible, and the people shout claim should be an hyper-camp claim, beyond every credibility. So, the sole manner to translate here 'theou' is 'of a god', or alike.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Greek grammar is not so precise as English with respect to articles.  It does not have indefinite articles at all, and the definite article has a different purpose/usage in Greek which is sometimes best translated as "the" in English, sometimes "a" or "an", and sometimes not at all.  So the presence of a definite article in Greek does not mean English will use one.

In Acts 12:22, it is not the presence of the article that is of interest, but rather its absence.

> ὁ δὲ δῆμος ἐπεφώνει **θεοῦ** φωνὴ καὶ οὐκ ἀνθρώπου (Acts 12:22, Greek TR)

Note that the bolded word, "Theou" in Greek, is not preceded by a definite article, because the only definite article in the text (ὁ/ho), which comes at the very beginning, is addressing the following noun, δῆμος, translated as "people"; it cannot apply again to God which is a separate noun entirely.

**Titles and Names with Definite Articles**

Names or titles in Greek usually are preceded by the definite article.  For example, "the John" and "the Christ" would be natural forms of expression in Greek.  In English translations, this usage of the definite article is generally dropped.  We see some passages where "the Christ" is preserved, and others where it will read simply "Christ."  English titles do not need this definite article to the same degree which Greek does.  (Greek occasionally omits the article as well.)

"God," used as a title referencing the supreme Deity, typically follows the definite article in Greek. This narrows the scope to the form of a specific name or title.

For example, both occurrences of "God" in the following Greek text are preceded by the definite article--but in English this article is dropped.

> They say unto him, Caesar's. Then saith he unto them, Render therefore
> unto Caesar the things which are Caesar's; and unto **God** the things
> that are **God's**. (Matthew 22:21, KJV)

Perhaps it is easy to see why we would not use "the" before "God" here--such a usage is not idiomatic to English and would be confusing.

So in Acts 12:22, the *absence* of the definite article clues us in to the fact that the reference is to a deity in general, and not to a specific one.  The grammar does not indicate that "god" should be a title.

**A Note on Capitalization**

It is important to note for those who may be unaware that at the time the Bible was written there was no distinction between uppercase and lowercase.  All Greek letters were written in uppercase.  Lowercase forms came into existence about a thousand years later, and, being easier to read for most of us, became the norm, displacing the all-uppercase forms in the copied manuscripts and the digital forms we read today.  So there cannot be any clues as to the original usage of God/god based on modern-day capitalization.

**Definite Article in the Greek Genitive Case**

A careful student of Greek will note that the definite article is frequently omitted with the genitive case nouns.  Nouns in genitive case typically indicate a prepositional usage, as of belonging or relating to something or someone else.  For example, the expression "son of God" may have "son" followed by the genitive case for "God", and may not have an article.  For example, consider the title or name given in Luke 1:35.

> And the angel answered and said unto her, The Holy Ghost shall come
> upon thee, and the power of the Highest shall overshadow thee:
> therefore also that holy thing which shall be born of thee shall be
> called **the Son of God.** (Luke 1:35, KJV)

Even though this is clearly a title, there is no definite article in this expression (bolded) in Greek.  The absence of the article is common with the genitive form.

But in Acts 12:22, the genitive form is used differently.  This is not referring to a son of God/a god.  The expression used might even be translated as "from a god [is the] voice."  The genitive is used here, not to show *belonging* so much as to indicate *origin*.  In that respect, the definite article might seem more customary with a title.  Indeed, genitive forms can and do carry the article at times.  Consider Matthew 8:29:

> And, behold, they cried out, saying, What have we to do with thee,
> Jesus, thou **Son of God**? art thou come hither to torment us before the
> time? (Matthew 8:29, KJV)

In Greek, this "of God" is actually "of **the** God"; and here, again, the expression is one where the addressee is being identified.  This usage, including the definite article, contrasts with that of Acts 12:22 where no article is present.

### Conclusion

The article in Greek is frequently employed to indicate a title or name.  Its absence in Acts 12:22 before "god" is noteworthy, even in the Greek genitive case where it might more often be omitted.  Where it is important to the title, even in the genitive case, the article is often included.  Therefore, while not an inflexible rule, the grammar of Acts 12:22 strongly leans toward "a god" being the most appropriate translation in English, as opposed to "God," which would be a proper title.